# Is there any best way to show pdf in iphone other than UIWebview in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

Can you please suggest me, best way to show pdf files in iphone since i had used UIWebview, it took 3 - 4 mins to render in webview. Also i faced _WebtryThreadLock error.

Srini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may have some large vector calculations going on in your PDF.  You can try re-constructing your PDF with flat images instead of vectors.

Code-wise QLPreviewController should be able to do what you want with a PDF, however it may use a UIWebView underneath.  UIDocumentInteractionController also has a preview mode, but I suspect that it is using a QLPreviewController itself for it's preview.

You can also use the low level PDF functions, though this will be more difficult to do.  Look at CGPDFDocument and it's related APIs in apple's documentation for more here.